# Parse CSV with spaces and semicolons

Tags: c, csv

I need to parse the following CSV file format:

```
# cat data.csv
20000530 172700;0.930200;0.930200;0.930200;0.930200;0
20000530 173500;0.930400;0.930500;0.930400;0.930500;0
20000530 173800;0.930400;0.930400;0.930300;0.930300;0
20000530 174300;0.930100;0.930100;0.930000;0.930000;0
```

Values are separated by character ; except the first one which is separated with a space character.

I have tried the following code to parse de CSV, but the time (second CSV value) is not parsed correctly.

```c
int read_data() {

    char _current_date[16];
    char _current_time[16];
    float _current_open;
    float _current_high;
    float _current_low;
    float _current_close;

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s %[ˆ;]%f;%f;%f;%f;", 
        _current_date, _current_time, 
        &_current_open, &_current_high, &_current_low, &_current_close) != EOF) {

      printf("%s\n", _current_date);
      printf("%s\n", _current_time);
    }
    fclose(fp);

}
```

Output is:

```
20000530

172700;0.930200;0.930200;0.930200;0.930200;0
0.930200;0.930200;0.930200;0
20000530
0.930200;0.930200;0.930200;0
173500;0.930400;0.930500;0.930400;0.930500;0
0.930500;0.930400;0.930500;0
20000530
0.930500;0.930400;0.930500;0
173800;0.930400;0.930400;0.930300;0.930300;0
0.930400;0.930300;0.930300;0
20000530
```

Comment: It might be easier to read lines with `fgets`, then split fields using `strtok`.

Comment: @user3121023 I have tried ˋ%[ˆ;];%fˋ but still same result

Comment: @user3121023 I added a variable to scan the trailing zero too, but still same result

Comment: @user3121023 well spotted!, I was using an Android laptop which seems to use weird characters. This fixes the issue.

Comment: That's not CSV -- not because it uses `;` rather than `,`, but because it uses two different delimiters. (That doesn't mean there's anything wrong with the format, just that calling it CSV is misleading.) Also, don't define identifiers that start with an underscore. Such identifiers are reserved to the implementation. (The rules are such that an identifier starting with an underscore and a lowercase letter is ok in some contexts, but it's easier just to avoid leading underscores altogether.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I think the closest name we can find for this format is CSV, even when it is not a pure CSV as you properly highlight. Thanks for the advice about leading underscores, I was not aware about it, I tend to use them for temporary stuff (probably this comes from my Python exposure where if I remember correctly a leading underscore usually means local to the class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the time (second CSV value) is not parsed correctly.

OP's format does not consume a `;` nor the final `0` and did not check the return value correctly.  Use `== 6`, not `!= EOF`.

```
//                        ; not consumed
//                                    0 not consumed
while(fscanf(fp, "%s %[ˆ;]%f;%f;%f;%f;", 
    _current_date, _current_time,                             //    == 6
    &_current_open, &_current_high, &_current_low, &_current_close) != EOF)
```

---

> Parse CSV with spaces and semicolons

To parse OP specific format, the following suggest various ideas.  It is not a CSV parser (comma separated values) as OP is not using commas.

---

1. Test for `fopen()` success

   ```
   if (fp == NULL) {
     // maybe add message
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   ```
2. Use `fgets()` to read the *line*  [@Steve Summit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948548/parse-csv-with-spaces-and-semicolons#comment86913590_49948548)

   ```
   char buf[100];   // suggest 2x expected need
   while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
   ```
3. Use `sscanf()` and record how much of the line was scanned with `"%n"`.  Use width limits when reading text into a string. [@user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3121023/user3121023).  I added a few spaces in the format to allow white-space before the `;`.  Maybe use `%15[ˆ; ]` to avoid any spaces in `_current_time`

   ```
     int n = 0;
     sscanf(buf, "%15s %15[ˆ;] ;%f ;%f ;%f ;%f ;0 %n", 
       _current_date, _current_time, 
       &_current_open, &_current_high, &_current_low, &_current_close,
       &n);
   ```
4. Test if `n` now points to the end of `buf`

   ```
     if (n == 0 || buf[n] != '\0') {
       // Handle failure in some manner
       break;
     }
     // else Success!
   ```
5. Use data.  Add sentinels, like `<>` to string output to help detect unexpected leading/trailing white-space.

   ```
     printf("<%s>\n", _current_date);
     printf("<%s>\n", _current_time);
   }
   ```
6. Clean-up

   ```
   fclose(fp);
   ```